# Invoke method from stream api in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am novice to java 8.I am trying below scenario.

```
class Numbers{
   private Long userId;
   private Long number1;
   private Long number2;

}

List<Numbers> list = new ArrayList();

Input == {
   "userId":1,
   "number1":10,
   "number2":20
}
{
   "userId":1,
   "number1":20,
   "number2":40
}
```

output:: Map

```
{
 "userId":1,
 "sum":90 // addition of all numbers associated with userId
}
```

I want to use java 8 stream api.

I am trying like this but it gives me error,

```
  Map<Long, Long> hashMap  =results.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Numbers::userId,Collectors.summingLong(?));
```

So my question,
Can i invoke below method from `Collectors.toMap()`

```
Long addNumbers(Long number1,Long number2){
return number1+number2;
}
```

Comment: you don't need `addNumbers` btw... that is whaat `Long::sum` already does

Comment: If I want to perform more complex operation on number data then its good have the seperate method for that operation(that method returns the number finally).How i can invoke that method from collectors.toMap?Any suggestions?

Comment: as any other method reference... `this::addNumbers` instead of `Long::sum` that I've used

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an easier way with `Collectors::groupingBy` with a downstream collector:

```
results.stream().collect(
     Collectors.groupingBy(
           Numbers::getUserId, Collectors.summingLong(x -> x.getNumber1() + x.getNumber2())
     )
);
```

You can still do it with `Collectors.toMap`:

```
results.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
         Numbers::getUserId,
         x -> x.getNumber1() + x.getNumber2(),
         Long::sum   
    )
);
```

Or without streams :

```
Map<Long, Long> all = new HashMap<>();
numbers.forEach(x -> all.merge(
                  x.getUserId(), 
                  x.getNumber1() + x.getNumber2(), 
                  Long::sum);
```